# onclick() jQuery/JavaScript Button to display piechart doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, click

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="flip" href="#feedbackmain" inline style="height:120px" type="button" name="feedbackLink">
        <img src="icons/report.png" inline style="height:80px"/><br/>Feedback
</a>
```

So I have this button as shown above and I am trying to trigger it to open a pie chart for me. Problem is that I can't seem to get the button to work. I can also create the piechart upon webpage load if possible but haven't been able to figure out how to do that either. My pie chart is made in jQplot and is generated like this:

```
function drawChart(data) {
     var data = data;

      var options = {
          title: 'Pie Chart',
          seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
              showDataLabels: true,
              dataLabels: 'value',
              fill: false,
              sliceMargin: 5,
              lineWidth: 5,
              startAngle: 45
            }
          },
          legend: { show:true, location: 'w' }
        };

      $.jqplot('chartDivId', data, options);
    }
```

Now, I tried calling the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    drawChart([[["data1",6],["data2",5],["data3",2]]]);
})
```

I get a transparent box where the chart is supposed to be drawn, but ... it's transparent. I can make a button with an onClick function on the same div with data-role: page and get that to work, but I'd rather have it load on startup as I need the data1,data2,data3 parameters loaded from MySQL via PHP. I can't even get contact with the button shown in the first snippet with the following code:

```
$("#feedbackLink").click(function()
        {
        alert("2");
        })
    });
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Either get the button to do it for me OR have the chart load automatically with the rest of the script.

EDIT: I even stripped it down to this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#test").click(function()
        {
            alert("2");
        })
})
```

And the button:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <input type="button" id="test" value="test"/>
</div>
```

I deleted basically everything else in the whole page, and still no damned contact :U

Comment: how do you get the parametrs do they read using ajax or passed as query varaibles from a php file ?

Comment: Haven't made that part yet, first I need the button to respond to the rest of the script.

Comment: do you tried with an id attribute instead of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the id attribute to the anchor so you can handle the click event with JQuery

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="flip" id="feedbackLink" href="#feedbackmain" inline style="height:120px" type="button" name="feedbackLink">
    <img src="icons/report.png" inline style="height:80px"/><br/>Feedback
</a>
```

also you need to make sure that your event handler is written in the $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#feedbackLink").click(function(){
      alert("2");
    })
});
```

Comment: Already tried that too. Just can't seem to find the connection between them :/

Comment: have you checked the console in google chrome or firefox
any error messages in the console ??

Comment: Finally. I found an error now. I did try it before I removed all other content and it kept saying that the official jQuery files had errors. But now I found a )} that should of been a }) to close document.ready. I got contact :D thanks alot ^^

Answer (score 1):

add a `id` attribute to the anchor link and then try... it will surely work

in jquery `#` resembles the id of the element

```
$("#feedbackLink").click(function()
        {
        alert("2");
        })
    });
```

Comment: Tried that as well without any luck :/ It should be placed in the document.ready part yes?